# my delete query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to delete from multiple tables in one query in mysql. it is giving me the following error:

ERROR:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `fields_data` ON posts.post_id = fields_data.post_id W' at line 1

```
<?php
include "connection.php";

$id=@$_GET['pid'];

$ssq="DELETE FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `fields_data` ON posts.post_id =   
fields_data.post_id WHERE posts.post_id= '$id'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$ssq);
if($query){
 header("location:home.php?del=The post has been deleted successfully");
 }
else{
echo "ERROR:".mysqli_error($con);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table name after `DELETE` keyword:

```
$ssq="DELETE `posts` FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `fields_data` ON posts.post_id =   
fields_data.post_id WHERE posts.post_id= '$id'";
```

Using alias names for better understanding

```
$ssq="DELETE p FROM `posts` as p INNER JOIN `fields_data` as fd ON p.post_id =   
fd.post_id WHERE p.post_id= '$id'";
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to delete the records from both tables, just specify the table names after `DELETE` keyword:

```
$ssq="DELETE `posts`,`fields_data` FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `fields_data` ON posts.post_id =   
fields_data.post_id WHERE posts.post_id= '$id'";
```

Comment: @MashhoodAli: Ofcourse, you can do it without alias name. I used it for better understanding. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @MashhoodAli: Edited my answer using both ways.

Comment: i dont know whats wrong..but the above query is only deleting from post table rows...

Comment: @MashhoodAli: You want to delete from both tables? Then see the edit in my answer.

Comment: @MashhoodAli: You are welcome, my friend. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

You often use the INNER JOIN clause in the SELECT statement to select records from a table that have corresponding records in other tables. To make it more convenient, MySQL also allows you to use the INNER JOIN clause with the DELETE statement to delete records from a table and also the corresponding records in other tables e.g., to delete records from both T1 and T2 tables that meet a particular condition, you use the following statement:

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition
```

Your code

```
$ssq="DELETE posts,fields_data FROM `posts` as posts INNER JOIN `fields_data`as fields_data ON posts.post_id =   
fields_data.post_id WHERE posts.post_id= '$id'";
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Comment: yeah thanks it worked...im afraid i cant select 2 answers.. @raging's was posted before..
thanks anyway..